# Why is the process.env object empty but I can access its properties?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, environment-variables

I have just come across the idea of using environment variables in a front end React codebase I am looking at. When I run the React app locally I can see that when I console.log process.env.VALUE, then this value will be logged out in the browser console.

However if I `console.log(process.env)` I only see an empty object. I've seen other answers for this on Stack Overflow but I couldn't understand them. It doesn't make sense to me how I can access the properties on process.env but I can't log process.env out. Isn't it just an object which contains all the environment variables that are set?

Comment: I don't know, when i ```console.log(process.env)``` is logged out to console but its not empty object

Answer (score 2):

The reason for that is because React naturally uses `webpack.DefinePlugin` when you are building your production build. That library basically makes your `process.env` variable to essentially be 'placeholders' - meaning that **all of the values are replaced during build time**. That's why `process.env` returns `{}`, while `process.env.NODE_ENV` returns the correct one for example.

Slightly off-topic, but in Next.js (a React framework), all environment variables are also replaced during build time (for security purposes). That means that `process.env` **is not a normal JavaScript object in Next.js**. Internally, they use `webpack.DefinePlugin` as well.

As an addition for the answer, the browser does not have access to `process.env`. React is basically compiled to HTML/CSS/JS - that means the application is just a static site. `process.env` is a Node.js thing.

Example:

- Imagine you have an environment variable called `FOO` with value `BAR` in whatever environment you desire when you build your app.
- You compile the application, React uses `webpack.DefinePlugin` to transform your `FOO` into `process.env.FOO`. It is literally `process.env.FOO`. The compiler **does not create an object called `process.env` with an attribute `FOO`.** Literally, the `process.env.FOO` is attached in the `window` object of your app.
- You assume that it's on `process.env.FOO`, and it does exist in your application during runtime.
- You falsely try to access `process.env` object (it is not and have never been an object) since the beginning of the compilation, and that's why it returns an empty object -- it simply is never an object to begin with for the reasons that I have explained in the above.

References:

- [DefinePlugin by Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/)
- [React.js Environment Variables](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/)
- [Next.js Environment Variables](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables)

Comment: Sorry but some of your answer didn't make sense to me, what do you mean placeholders? if they are placeholders then why does process.env.NODE_ENV return a value but process.env doesn't? isn't process.env an object which contains NODE_ENV?

Comment: Also in the browser console, I am able to see the value of process.env.XXXX being logged out but I don't see process.env so how is this possible?

Comment: Because of the `DefinePlugin`, `process.env` is technically not an object - `process.env.XXX` is basically a literal variable / value of `process.env.XXX`, not an attribute of an object. `process.env` in browser means nothing and will not output anything, as it's never an object in the first place.

Comment: Could you provide an example please to make it clearer, the setup I'm working with is not using dotenv files but it does have the --env flag in the package.json, so how am I able to access process.env.XXXX in the browser? are you saying those process.env.XXXX are replaced with values by the time it gets into the browser? so even where I'm doing the console.log it has replaced that variable with the actual value?

Comment: Sure. Check out my updated answer. Like I said, `process.env.XXX` is literally `process.env.XXX` (as in `const process.env.XXX` to say it roughly) attached to the `window` object.  `process.env` has never been an object in React app.