# Optional chaining with process?.env fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

In node.js/ReactJs if I try to do

```
console.log(process);
console.log(process?.env)
```

[image]

it will throw an error that `process` is not defined, while doing

```
console.log(process.env)
```

works fine.
The question is: why it is failing?

Comment: What's your node and react version ?

Comment: My understanding is that: `?:` is the Ternary Operator. `?.` is Optional-chaining.

Comment: Not to be a pedant, but this is the [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) operator. Many developers, myself included, have substituted ternary operators with the chaining operator, and they do very similar things, but they are distinct.

Comment: Your' right guys, I've used wrong name

Comment: In regards to `process` and `process.env` - please see if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69721662/13658816) is helpful.

Comment: is that code running blindly in your browser? there's no `process` in the browser

Comment: @jsN00b thank you, that answers to my question

Comment: if you are using last version of create-react-app, process is undefined. You can read more here https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11951 https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/11764