# process?.env?.REACT_APP_VAR_NAME causing Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

The following code in our front-end was causing a bug:

```
<span style={{ color: 'red' }}>{process?.env?.REACT_APP_HEADER_SUFFIX ?? ''}</span>
```

The following error is shown:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
at appNameWithEnvironmentMenuItem (MobileHeaderComponent.jsx:27:1)
at MobileHeaderComponent (MobileHeaderComponent.jsx:51:1)
at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14803:1)
at updateFunctionComponent (react-dom.development.js:17034:1)
```

I did some research and found this issue: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11773.

However, looks like it is not a solution for our case. Because changing this code to following solved the issue.

```
<span style={{ color: 'red' }}>{process.env.REACT_APP_HEADER_SUFFIX}</span>
```

Why would `process?` with `?` break the application? Is there some logical explanation for this?

Comment: That "legacy" code can't be too old, because the `?.` and `??` operators are pretty recent.

Comment: you're right, it is 2021. let's call it ex-colleague code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that `process`, which is a [Node API](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#process), does not exist in the browser environment - your code is running in your users' browsers, and has access neither to the env vars in your build environment nor the ones on their machine - therefore `process.env` is a reference error. So why does it work *without* optional chaining?

What CRA does for its [custom environment variables](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/) feature, using Webpack's [`DefinePlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/), is replace the **literal text** `process.env.REACT_APP_HEADER_SUFFIX` in your source code with the (JSON-stringified) value of that environment variable in your environment *at build time*. For example, with your:

```
<span style={{ color: 'red' }}>{process.env.REACT_APP_HEADER_SUFFIX}</span>
```

given e.g. `REACT_APP_HEADER_SUFFIX=foobar` at build time, the plugin is given a mapping like*:

```
{
  "process.env.REACT_APP_HEADER_SUFFIX": '"foobar"'
}
```

and the code would therefore be transformed to:

```
<span style={{ color: 'red' }}>{"foobar"}</span>
```

As `"process?.env?.REACT_APP_HEADER_SUFFIX" !== "process.env.REACT_APP_HEADER_SUFFIX"` it is **not** replaced and the expression `process?.env?.REACT_APP_HEADER_SUFFIX ?? ''` is still in your code at runtime, hence the reference error.

It's the same reason you can't do things like:

- `const envVars = process.env;` and then use `envVars.REACT_APP_HEADER_SUFFIX`; or
- `process.env["REACT_APP_HEADER_SUFFIX"]`.

More broadly this build-time configuration generally means you have to rebuild your app for every environment it needs to run in, which isn't ideal; I've written more about this [on my blog](https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2020/Sep/19/spa-config.html).

Related:

- [Why is the process.env object empty but I can access its properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69715833/3001761) via
- [Optional chaining with process?.env fails](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70894671/3001761)

* *Incidentally the creation of this mapping is why the `REACT_APP_` prefix is needed, otherwise all of your build environment's variables will be exposed to your client app, and then [bad things happen](https://wale.id.au/posts/iviewed-your-api-keys/).*