# How do I set my enviroment variables for create-react-app?

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, create-react-app, dotenv

I have my create-react-app with Express running perfectly fine on localhost but now that I want to publish it I need to move some stuff to environment variables obviously.

The thing is that I created my `.env` file in my `/src` folder (I can't move it to the root directory if I want to be able to access to it from my `/src`) and named variables with the REACT_APP_ prefix, like:

```
REACT_APP_USERNAME="TESTNAME"
```

I'm getting that `.env` file with

```
const myEnv = require('../.env')
```

Then in one of my components I try to get that variable but it´s not there... if I `console.log(proccess.env)` I can see the default values but nothing about my vars, what am I missing?

Comment: You don't have to require the .env file, React will load the env variables for you. https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

Comment: Just did it @JuniusL, no errors but anyway I can´t see my variables...

Comment: Then give a [mre] _of that_, require-ing the file certainly isn't going to work. Note it's not the case that process.env is populated with the variables, as I explain in https://stackoverflow.com/a/76440819/3001761

Answer (score 0):

Like [Junius L](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2562564/junius-l) said, "you don´t have to require the .env file" so after I deleted that require() I could move it to the proper root directory (instead of the /src directory) and problem fixed.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I used the "Answer your own question" button as it´s what I did