# Jest does not respect ENV variable when override in a test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I have a component that looks like this:

```
const isPersonalSite: boolean = process.env.PERSONAL_SITE === 'true';
const isFeatureEnabled: boolean = process.env.IS_FEATURE_ENABLED === 'true';

export const ProfileMenu = () => {
    console.log('PERSONAL_SITE component', process.env.PERSONAL_SITE)
    return (
        <>
            {!isPersonalSite && isFeatureEnabled &&
                <a href="http://test.com">Test 1</a>
            }

            {!isPersonalSite && !isFeatureEnabled &&
                <a href="http://test2.com">Test 2</a>
            }

            {isPersonalSite &&
                <a href="http://test3.com">Test 3</a>
            }

            <a href="/logout">Logout</a>
        </>
    )
}
```

and I am trying to write a test using JestJS. My `jest.config.js` contains the following definition after `module.exports`:

```
process.env = Object.assign(process.env, {
    PERSONAL_SITE: false,
    IS_FEATURE_ENABLED: false
});
```

The test looks like this:

```
describe("ProfileDropDownMenu", () => {
    const env = process.env

    beforeEach(() => {
        jest.resetModules()
        process.env = { ...env }
    })
    
    afterEach(() => {
        process.env = env
    })
    
    it('render the menu', () => {
        process.env.PERSONAL_SITE = 'true'

        console.log('PERSONAL_SITE test', process.env.PERSONAL_SITE)
        
        render(
            <ProfileMenu />
        )
        
        expect(screen.getByText('Test 3')). toBeInTheDocument();
        expect(screen.getByText('Logout')). toBeInTheDocument();
    })
})
```

From the above, I would expect the test to pass, but it is failing instead saying that `Test 3` does not exist in the document and I wonder why. `PERSONAL_SITE test` prints out `true`. `PERSONAL_SITE component` also prints out `true` but the test won't pass, why?

Comment: This is fundamentally not a good way to configure a React app. Rather than having the URL be configuration you've made it code, triggered by _other_ configuration. But also you're likely using some tool to replace `process.env` (which [does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76440819/3001761)) at build time, which means rebuilding entirely to get a different value. [Here](https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2020/Sep/19/spa-config.html) are some other ways to approach this, and why you might consider them. (But as pointed out below the immediate problem is _when_ the variables are evaluated.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isPersonalSite` and `isFeatureEnabled` are declared outside the function `ProfileMenu`. In fact, those two const are declared outside of any function.

What does it mean ? It means that their value is calculated when the file is read, so when it is imported.

So, when you are calling `ProfileMenu`, `isPersonalSite` and `isFeatureEnabled` are already set to `true` / `false` (it looks like it's `false` in this case).

**How to fix this ? There are multiple ways :**

1. Set the declaration of the two constants inside the function `ProfileMenu`
2. Import your component dynamically after setting process.env with `import()` or `require()`
3. Use jest setup files, you could prepare your testing environment (global mocks, global env vars) before executing tests : https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#setupfiles-array

Each way has pros and cons depending on what you want to achieve. I'd avoid the 1st one because you shouldn't edit your codebase to make tests pass, but in some cases you may need to code in a way that will simplify testing for you.

Comment: After some more research, I ended up discovering the (1) option which is the one I decided to use, this is a new component I am adding to the code so I was developing and adding tests at the same time. For (2) can you add an example? (3) Changing this could be a big problem for me because we are a big team and the rest of the team is tempted to refuse this kind of change because it could break the entire test suite

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is a **typo**

it is **`.toBeInTheDocument()`** instead of **`.toBeInDocument()`**

I tried same code you provided and the Test pass.

Hope this helps

Comment: it was a typo, yes, but it was not intended or part of the original code it was a human error while writing the OP here. It is weird that the test passed for you. You might have a different configuration than mine because believe me I tried everything on my hands and could not make it to work like it is on the OP :|